# c++ generic pixel array (supporting multiple channels) for image class

Tags: c++, image, pixel

I am currently working on a simple image class in c++ which uses FreeImage internally to load and parse the image files. Anyways I am not really sure about how to implement my pixel array as generic, simple and safe as possible. For instance the class is supposed to handle different channel counts. Since for now I simply want to decide which pixel format to use based on the file type and pixel information freeImage gives me, the exact decisions have to be made at runtime, when actually loading the image. I think the only way to deal with this is to have a pointer to some abstract "Pixels" baseclass in the image class definition, and then allocate the correct format on the heap like this (basically a factory pattern):

```
//pseudo code
class Image{

    template<class T, class TNumChannels>
    struct Pixel
    {
        T v[TNumChannels];
    };

    class BasePixelArray{...};

    class RGBPixelArray : 
            public std::vector<Pixel<uint8, 3> >, 
            public BasePixelArray
    {
        ...
    };

private:

    BasePixelArray * m_pixelPtr;


public:
    void loadImage(const std::string & _bla)
    {
        //parse and decide what pixelformat to use, i.e
        m_pixelPtr = static_cast<BasePixelArray*>(new RGBPixelArray);
        //fill array
        ....
    }

};
```

i don't think this is ideal at all since I would like to avoid allocating from the heap , but since it has to be done at runtime I could not really think of anything else, so I was wondering if anybody of you guys might have a better idea!

Thanks

Comment: Do not derive from std::vector, that class is not designed for being baseclass. Make it a member instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all dimensions of image beforehand and if it's a large image (actually, it should be relatively small image), you can make it compile-time allocation on stack. If you don't know those details or you want to allocate large image, then allocation on heap is the only solution.

For more inspiration, you may want to take a look at the `image` and `any_image` models from [Boost.GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) library.

Comment: thanks, well I am actually aware that I kind of have to allocate on the heap, but I would prefer a solution where I don't have to create the std::vector on the heap, but rather let it manage its memory internally. That would make it safer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your platform, but from the Windows perspective, here's my advice:

- Stack, but keep in mind that the default user stack size is 1MB, which can be changed if you control the thread creation using `_beginthreadex()`.
- Heap, probably the most common choice
- Use `::VirtualAlloc` directly if you alloc/dealloc either very large buffers, or alloc/dealloc very frequently

Comment: Thanks, I am on OSX and I need cross platform solutions. Sorry for not being clear about "heap", see comment to mloskot's post.